# Convert date range to set of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-science

I am trying to take a table that has a structure similar to this:

```
ID      START_DATE  END_DATE
1111    01/01/14    06/01/14
1111    08/01/14    12/01/14
1111    01/01/15    03/01/15
1111    05/01/15    11/01/15
```

And get a structure which consecutive rows contain dates between START_DATE and END_DATE, including the dates:

```
ID      DATE_FIELD
1111    01/01/14
1111    02/01/14
1111    03/01/14
1111    04/01/14
1111    05/01/14
1111    06/01/14
1111    08/01/14
1111    09/01/14
1111    10/01/14
1111    11/01/14
1111    12/01/14
1111    01/01/15
1111    02/01/15
1111    03/01/15
1111    05/01/15
1111    06/01/15
1111    07/01/15
1111    08/01/15
1111    09/01/15
1111    10/01/15
1111    11/01/15
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) in lateral join, i.e. for each row of original table:

```
select id, d::date as date_field
from my_table, 
generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') d;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e8c8a/1)